# Subtract current item with next indexed item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to subtract the current item in the loop with the next indexed item, but I'm just getting the following error: **undefined method `[]' for 0.0:Float**

```
<% @trial.methods.each_with_index do |e, index| %>
  <%= (e.total - e.total[index+1]) %><br />
  <%= Time.at(e.try(:assessment).try(:assessment_date)/1000).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %><br />
  <%= e.try(:assessment).try(:degrees) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think there is an easier way of doing that. Look at the following example.

```
# An array of 5 random numbers
a =  [7,12,1,2,3]

# Iterate through the indices of the array
a.each_index do |i|
    # We only show the result of a[i+1] - a[i]
    # given i+1 is still in range of the array
    puts "#{a[i+1] - a[i]}" if (i+1) < a.length
end
```

This should output  `5 -11 1 1` each on a new line.

Similarly, you could do something like this:

```
<% @trial.methods.each_index do |i| %>
  <% if i + 1 < e.total.length %>
    <%= (e.total[i] - e.total[index+1]) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= 0 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The conditional works with this. But falls short of the <%= (e.total[i] - e.total[index+1]) %> line.

Answer (score 2):

Use [#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to build a subarray of consecutive pairs, then map it:

```
array = [7,12,1,2,3]

array.each_cons(2).map{ |e| e.last - e.first }

# => [5, -11, 1, 1]
```

A slight alternative:

```
array.each_cons(2).map{ |a, b| b - a }
```

Of course, you can change to `a - b` or whatever you need.

The first part does this:

```
array.each_cons(2).each {|e| p e}

# => [7, 12]
# => [12, 1]
# => [1, 2]
# => [2, 3]
```

Comment: This works, but not quite what I was looking for. Maybe should of explained in more detail that I have other objects reliant on the loop as well. Doing .map just does't suit my needs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Consider to add a sample of input array and the expected result, I could add an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerable#reduce to achieve this:

```
a =  [7,12,1,2,3]
a.reduce(&:-) # -11
```

So for your case:

```
@trial.methods.map{|e| e.total}.reduce(&:-)
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce on its usage

Comment: I get the following error: undefined method `reduce' for 0.1:Float

Comment: You have to run it on an Enumerable (like an Array). Can you show the code that you're trying to run ?

Comment: I think the problem is that there are associations involved.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include an example for your specific case. I updated the answer

Comment: This works, but not quite what I was looking for. Maybe should of explained in more detail that I have other objects reliant on the loop as well. Doing .map just does't suit my needs. Thanks for the help.